# Isosceles triangle generated by 3 touching circles

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry

I was playing in GeoGebra and came across a coincidence I could not explain:

> A circle with center $C_1$ is internally tangent to a circle with center $C_2$ at point $S$, and externally tangent to a circle with center $C_3$ at point $R$. The point $C_3$ lies on the $C_2$ circle. In addition, circle $C_3$ intersects circle $C_2$ at P and Q.
> Extend R$C_1$ to meet circle $C_2$ at $U$. Next extend $RP$ and $US$ to meet at $T$. Prove that when points $S$, $R$, and $Q$ are collinear, then $\triangle RST$ is isosceles.

Please refer to the GeoGebra diagram if the problem statement was unclear. [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SLMryH5LcjBuelrl75OWMGXwg4_saGUS/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Added link in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We perform an angle chase. Let $\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3$ refer to the circles with center $C_1,C_2,C_3$ respectively. First, we start off with the following:

**Claim.** $C_1 C_3 Q C_2$ is a parallelogram (in that order).

*Proof.* Since, $S,R,Q$ are collinear, a homothety (i.e., dilation) at $S$ that sends $\omega_1$ to $\omega_2$ also sends $C_1$ to $C_2$ and $R$ to $Q$, so $C_1R \parallel C_2Q$. Furthermore, a negative homothety at $R$ sending $\omega_1$ to $\omega_3$ also sends $S$ to $Q$ (again because $S,R,Q$ are collinear), so $SC_1 \parallel C_3Q \Rightarrow C_1C_2 \parallel C_3Q$, which finishes.

(You can also phrase this part with only angle chasing, using the many isosceles triangles around.)

Now, angle chasing suffices. First, we have:
$$
\angle TSR = 180 - \angle USQ = 180 - \angle UC_3Q = \angle C_2QC_3,
$$
(where the last equality is by using the parallelogram proven above). We also have that $
\angle TRS = 180 - \angle PRQ 
$, but $\angle PRQ$ is equal to half the measure of the major arc $PQ$ (in circle $\omega_3$), so $180 - \angle PRQ$ is equal to half the measure of the minor arc $PQ$, or $\frac{\angle PC_3Q}{2}$. Now:
$$
\angle TRS = 180 - \angle PRQ = \frac{\angle PC_3Q}{2} = \angle C_2C_3Q
$$
so it suffices to show that $\triangle C_2C_3Q$ is isosceles which is immediate as $C_2C_3 = C_2Q$. (In fact, we have proven the stronger claim that $\triangle STR \sim \triangle QC_2C_3$!)
[image: Diagram]